# Why it's possible to instantiate String and not possible for Number(Long,Double,Integer...)?

Tags: java, string, instantiation, long-integer

Hi why it's possible to instantiate String and not possible for Numbers .I have made an example for that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    String a = "s";
    String newInstance = a.getClass().newInstance();
    System.out.println(newInstance);
    Double b = 0d;
    Double newInstance2 = b.getClass().newInstance();
    System.out.println(newInstance2);
}
```

Comment: What result you would expect for `Double.class.newInstance()`?

Answer (score 12):

Calling [newInstace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) invokes the default constructor. [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) does not have one.

If you want to instantiate using reflection then you have to get one of the Contructors of the class using [Class.#getConstructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) by passing it the appropriate argument types and then call its method [Constructor#newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) by passing it the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`java.lang.String` has an empty constructor (calling `new String()` is the same as calling `new String("")`).
Numbers, on the other hand, don't have no-arg constructors (what would the value of a `new Double()` be anyway? there is no equivalent to an "empty number"), and thus can't be invoked this way, even not by reflection.